# Stuck in using media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I was making a website and after completion, I was applied `@media` but i ran into a problem.

After using `@media` on my logo or anything i run it, but chrome is not detecting the `@media`. Then to solve this problem i made a random footer and aplied `@media` on it. I set the font to be smaller and it was working fine.

Why it is not working on the body or the header?

```
<!-- body -->
<div class="body">
<section class="body-left">
  <p class="left-text">SEE YOURSELF BY. <br> <span>VANITY FAIR</span></p>
<video autoplay loop src="img/video.mp4">
</video>
</section>
<section class="body-right">
  <p class="right-text"><span class="quote">"</span><br>I may be a beginner at some things, <br> but I've got a black belt in shopping. <br> — Phyllis Nefler </p>
<img src="img/female.jpg" alt="sdf" class="female">
</section>
</div>
<!-- end body -->
<footer>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

In this code where the body is the media is not working there. but the dummy footer which i created it is working there. Strange.

```
}
.quote{
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family:'Playfair Display', sans-serif;
}


/* body section right */
 p{
  width: 100%;
  height: 30vh;
  font-size: 40px;
}
@media all and (max-width:1000px) {
p{
  font-size: 20px;
}

}
```

In this example
media on the quote(body-right) is not working

and p which is the dummy footer media is working there

There are no errors.

Comment: Can you create a Codepen example?

Comment: https://codepen.io/ankit-panda/pen/VwvevaJ

Comment: Its working in your codepen, `.quote` contains only the `"` and its `font-size` is changing correctly

Comment: but the vanity fair is not working i mean .logo

Comment: Where's the media query for that in your code?

Comment: i wrote it again check plz https://codepen.io/ankit-panda/pen/VwvevaJ

Comment: i tried every alternative so i cleared all the media

Comment: The problem is that when you set `h1` style with JS, it becomes an inline style and you will need `!important` to override it, but better is to set it using the same selector `header .logo` in css file, and remove the JS statement. It will work

Comment: i did not use JS though i am so confused. i know its showing js in codepen but i have not created a file with js extension there are only 2 files. .html and css

Comment: What is this line in the JS tab? `document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].style.fontSize = "80px";`

Comment: yeah man idk where that came from

Comment: If all is working for you, you can mark the answer as accepted by clicking the grey tick next to it

Comment: ok i will but its not :(

Comment: But now the logo is also resizing in the codepen, what's the issue?

Comment: its resizing after i deleated js code document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].style.fontSize = "80px"; this.  But in my actual project i cant delete it and idk how cuz there is nothing regarding js.

Comment: I also tried media with navbar thats also not working. rip i think it is bugged

Comment: If you can't change js just add `font-size: 30px !important;`

Comment: loo vanity fair is changing right but the right-text is not. It was changing before u remember?

Comment: For me, the media query is working for logo. Just switch codepen to full screen view.

Comment: ok bro thanks good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because `.quote` is more specific. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

You can use the same class in the media query:

```
@media all and (max-width:1000px) {
   .quote {
      font-size: 20px;
   }    
}
```